# How to update database using dictionary with linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, dictionary

I work with .NET Framework 4.5, linq, using MVC. Now I must change the code in the controller.

I don't know how to get and add new values from dictionary.

Comment: Are you wanting to loop over the values that are in the dictionary?  Or Are you wanting to add new values to the dictionary?

Comment: Loop over the values that are in the dictionary to change Description in my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will let you loop over your dictionary values:

```
foreach (string key in dictionary.Keys) {
    string value = dictionary[key];
    //Now, do something with value, such as add to database
}
```

And this will let you find a specific dictionary value:

```
string key = "a_key";
if (dictionary.ContainsKey(key)) {
    string value = dictionary[key];
    //Now do something with value
}
```

I think you are looking to do something like the second example above.

What's confusing about your code example is that you have `!dictionary.ContainsKey`, which means that the key does not exist in the dictionary, but your comment says `//here must be these new key-value from dictionary`.  This makes me think that maybe you intend for `dictionary.ContainsKey` rather than `!dictionary.ContainsKey` and that you then want to retrieve the value and do something with it.  But I'm not sure.

In any case, perhaps you are asking simply how to get the value out of the dictionary, and in that case, you may find the `dictionary[key]` notation using brackets to be useful.  Is that what you were going for?

Comment: Yes, you are right about  !dictionary.ContainsKey , I've made a stupid mistake. And this second example was exactly that I was asking for, thak you very much!