# Update data in list if it already exits

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists `List<T> existingValues` & `List<T> newValues`

foreach item in `newvalues` I check if it exists in `existingValues`(I check existence of value based on primary key value), if it does not exist i will add it to `existingValues`.

Now if value already exists in `existingValues` I want to check if any columns values are diffenrent and if they are different I would like to update them, how can I do this?

```
foreach(var item in newvalues)
{
  if(!existingValues.Any(x => x.PrimaryKeyVal == item.PrimaryKeyVal))
  {
   newValues.Add(item);
  }

  if (existingValues.Any(x => x.PrimaryKeyVal == item.PrimaryKeyVal))
  {
    //do something here to check if both rows are same, if not update the row with new values
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you not just set all the properties from one to the other? If they're different they'll change, if not they won't. Also, you should probably use a dictionary instead of any, it would be much faster.

Comment: Use `intersect` method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065593/find-the-intersection-of-two-lists-in-linq

Comment: @Mhd if he's going that route, you probably want to use `Except` since he wants to change the values that are different.

Comment: @PeterDuniho this isn't a duplicate of that question in the slightest...

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is correct except that you have to do the update before the insert.

```
foreach(var item in newvalues)
{
  var existingItem = existingValues.Where(x => x.PrimaryKeyVal == item.PrimaryKeyVal).FirstOrDefault();
  if (existingItem != null && (x.Prop1 != item.Prop1 || x.Prop2 != item.Prop2 )))
  {
    //do something here to check if both rows are same, if not update the row with new values
    existingItem .Prop1 != item.Prop1; 
    existingItem .Prop2 != item.Prop2;

  }
  else if(existingItem == null)
  {
    newValues.Add(item);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that using a dictionary will help you (using the PrimaryKeyVal as key and them get the value and change it like in the examples below)

see -

[How to update value of a key in dictionary in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123043/how-to-update-value-of-a-key-in-dictionary-in-c)

[How to update database using dictionary with linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242752/how-to-update-database-using-dictionary-with-linq)